# Groupby, sum by month and calculate standard deviation divide by mean in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

For `df`:

```
    id          Date        ITEM_ID TYPE    VALUE  YearMonth
0   13710750    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       10     2019-07
1   13710760    2019-07-01  SLM607  O       10     2019-07
2   13710770    2019-07-03  SLM607  O       2      2019-07
3   13710780    2019-09-03  SLM607  O       5      2019-09
4   13667449    2019-08-02  887643  O       7      2019-08
5   13667450    2019-08-02  792184  O       1      2019-08
6   13728171    2019-09-17  SLM607  I       1      2019-09
7   13667452    2019-08-02  794580  O       3      2019-08
```

reproducible example:

```
data = {
    "id": [
        13710750,
        13710760,
        13710770,
        13710780,
        13667449,
        13667450,
        13728171,
        13667452,
    ],
    "Date": [
        "2019-07-01",
        "2019-07-01",
        "2019-07-03",
        "2019-09-03",
        "2019-08-02",
        "2019-08-02",
        "2019-09-17",
        "2019-08-02",
    ],
    "ITEM_ID": [
        "SLM607",
        "SLM607",
        "SLM607",
        "SLM607",
        "887643",
        "792184",
        "SLM607",
        "794580",
    ],
    "TYPE": ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "I", "O"],
    "YearMonth": [
        "2019-07",
        "2019-07",
        "2019-07",
        "2019-09",
        "2019-08",
        "2019-08",
        "2019-09",
        "2019-08",
    ],
    "VALUE": [10, 10, 2, 5, 7, 1, 1, 3],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to group `df` by `ITEM_ID`, sum `VALUE` for each month using `YearMonth`, if there is no data for a month, create a row with `0` value for that month.The time period should be from `2019-07` to `2020-06` which is the financial year. Then I want to calculate the standard deviation of monthly summed `Value`, divided by mean. So each `ITEM_ID` would have one final value of standard deviation/mean for the year.

I did the first step with

```
df.groupby(['ITEM_ID', 'YearMonth']).sum().reset_index()
```

to calculate the monthly sum, but I'm not sure how to continue from here. Any idea is appreciated, thx.

---

An example as to how we calculate the standard deviation for each `ITEM_ID`

Using `ITEM_ID ==SLM607` for example,

```
Month    Sum of VALUE
2019-07  22 (10 + 10 + 2)
2019-09  6 (5 + 1)
```

For other months from 2019-07-01 to 2020-06-30, we assume `0` for each month.

Hence, the standard deviation for `ITEM_ID ==SLM607` would be the standard deviation of the list `[22, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, which gives the result:

```
np.std([22, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) = 6.155395104206463 (or 6.4291005073286 for sample std dev)
```

Apologies for any confusion caused in the original question. I'm trying to understand the reason of the difference in magnitude with the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step gets you the sums by object + month, but I'll just copy it here for completeness (note that I only sum VALUE since the ID's are numerically meaningless; you can group by them if you want to keep them around):

```
In [1]: by_month = df.groupby(['ITEM_ID', 'YearMonth'])['VALUE'].sum().reset_index()

In [2]: by_month
Out[2]:
  ITEM_ID YearMonth  VALUE
0  792184   2019-08      1
1  794580   2019-08      3
2  887643   2019-08      7
3  SLM607   2019-07     22
4  SLM607   2019-09      6
```

Now you want three values: the number of months being considered, then the std and mean of each item over that span. This gets a bit trickier if different objects were available over different durations, so I'll stick with the easier case of assuming all objects were available over the same duration, which I'll call `months = 12` (you specify that the time range of interest is a whole year).

The equations for mean and standard deviation both assume we know the correct N (12, in your case). We could pad the dataframe with 0's to allow Pandas' built-in `mean` and `std` equations to work, or we could implement our own functions that perform the padding on-demand. The latter sounds simpler to me.

```
In [3]: months = 12

In [4]: def mean_over_months(data):
   ...:     return np.mean(list(data) + [0] * (months - len(data)))
   ...:

In [5]: def std_over_months(data):
   ...:     return np.std(list(data) + [0] * (months - len(data)))
   ...:

In [6]: by_month.groupby('ITEM_ID')['VALUE'].agg(mean_over_months)
Out[6]:
ITEM_ID
792184    0.083333
794580    0.250000
887643    0.583333
SLM607    2.333333
Name: VALUE, dtype: float64
```

Now just perform the desired computation:

```
In [7]: item_means = by_month.groupby('ITEM_ID')['VALUE'].agg(mean_over_months)

In [8]: item_stds = by_month.groupby('ITEM_ID')['VALUE'].agg(std_over_months)

In [9]: item_stds / item_means
Out[9]:
ITEM_ID
792184    3.464102
794580    3.464102
887643    3.464102
SLM607    2.755329
Name: VALUE, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Just a small addition, mean could be calculated via `by_month.groupby("ITEM_ID")["VALUE"].sum() / 12`, no need for auxiliary function in this case.

Comment: Thank you scnerd for the beautiful solution. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# convert date string to datetiem
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# create a date range for your fiscal year
dr = pd.date_range('2019-07-01', '2020-06-01', freq='M').to_period('M')
# groupby year, month and item id and then sum the value column
g = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.to_period('M'), 'ITEM_ID'])['VALUE'].sum()
# reindex the grouped multiindex with your new fiscal year date range and your item ids
new_df = g.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dr, g.index.levels[1]], names=['Date', 'ITEM_ID']), fill_value=0).to_frame()
# create a groupby object 
new_g = new_df.groupby(level=1)['VALUE']
# std divided by the mean of the groupby object
new_g.std()/new_g.mean()

ITEM_ID
792184    3.316625
794580    3.316625
887643    3.316625
SLM607    2.631636
Name: VALUE, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the succinct solution. I calculated a few 'ITEM_ID' and it seemed the answer is slightly different, do you know why?

Comment: If you are calculating the standard deviation using `numpy` then the answer will be different than `pandas`, which I am using in my solution. Pandas' `groupby.std` function uses one degree of freedom as the default where `numpy.std` uses zero as the default. I hope that helps answer your question and you can read the `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.std` and `numpy.std` documentation for additional information.